# Pandas groupby n rows starting from bottom of df

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
Week    Sales
1        10
2        15
3        10
4        20
5        20
6        10
7        15
8        10
```

I would like to group every 3 weeks and sum up sales. I want so start with the bottom 3 weeks. If there are less than 3 weeks left at the top like in this example, these weeks should be ignored. Desired output is this:

```
Week    Sales
5-3       50
8-6       35
```

I tried this on my original df `df.reset_index(drop=True).groupby(by=lambda x: x/N, axis=0).sum()`
but this solution is not starting from the bottom rows.

Can anyone point me into the right direction here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try inverse the data with `.iloc[::-1]`:

```
N=3
(df.iloc[::-1].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//N)
   .agg({'Week': lambda x: f'{x.iloc[0]}-{x.iloc[-1]}',
         'Sales': 'sum'
        })
)
```

Output:

```
  Week  Sales
0  8-6     35
1  5-3     50
2  2-1     25
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with period aggregation, I usually use `.resample` as it is fixable in binning data with different time periods

```py
import io
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Week  Sales
1   10
2   15
3   10
4   20
5   20
6   10
7   15
8   10"""), sep='\s+',).astype(int)

# reverse data and transform int weeks to actual date time 

dataf = dataf.iloc[::-1]
dataf['Week'] = dataf['Week'].map(lambda x: timedelta(weeks=x))

# set date object to index for resampling
dataf = dataf.set_index('Week')

# now we resample
dataf.resample('21d').sum() # 21days
```

::: Note: the label is misleading. And setting `kind='period'` does raises error